# Unable to stub external request - Wrong regexp?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec-rails, webmock

I'm trying to craft a `stub_request` that matches all requests to *fcm.googleapis.com*. Our backend is supposed to send a push notification to its users when new Posts or Comments is created. Our tests trigger a lot of requests to fcm.googleapis.com, that's why I need a generic matcher.

**EDIT:** The test failed because I had added `stub_request` to the spec_helper. The failing test was not rspec, but an ordinary `ActionController::TestCase` test. My bad! :-|

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
 18 RSpec.configure do |config|
 19   require_relative "../test/mock_helper"
 20   require "webmock/rspec"
 21
 22   WebMock.disable_net_connect!
 23   config.before(:each) do
 24     stub_request(:post, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send").
 25         with(body: /.*/).
 26         to_return(status: 200)
 27
```

But when I run the tests it does not look like WebMock cares about my stub_request. What might be wrong?

**Running tests**

```
    Error:
    PostsControllerTest#test_should_create_post:
    WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError: Real HTTP connections are disabled. 
Unregistered request: POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send with body 
'{"registration_ids":[null],"notification":
{"title":"Fred Flintstone har skrevet en melding i Bedrock Sportsballteam",
"text":"New post!?"},"data":{"notification":{"avatar":null,"group_id":131900578,
"issued_at":"2018-06-25T13:37:28.746+02:00",
"full_name":"Fred Flintstone","id":700,"post_id":980190963,
"role_id":1}}}' with headers {'Authorization'=>'key=KEY', 'Content-Type'=>'application/json'}

    You can stub this request with the following snippet:

    stub_request(:post, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send").
      with(:body => "{\"registration_ids\":[null],\"notification\":
{\"title\":\"Fred Flintstone har skrevet en melding i Bedrock Sportsballteam\",
\"text\":\"New post!?\"},\"data\":{\"notification\":
{\"avatar\":null,\"group_id\":131900578,
\"issued_at\":\"2018-06-25T13:37:28.746+02:00\",
\"full_name\":\"Fred Flintstone\",\"id\":700,\"post_id\":980190963,\"role_id\":1}}}",
           :headers => {'Authorization'=>'key=KEY', 
           'Content-Type'=>'application/json'}).
      to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

---

My backend should send a push notifiction to our users when a new Post is created updated.

**app/models/post.rb**

```
 16 class Post < ApplicationRecord
 25   after_save :send_notifications

 82   def send_notifications
 83     PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS.new_post_in_group(post: self)
 84   end
```

**bin/rails test test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb:57**

```
 57   test "should create post" do
 58     assert_difference("Post.count") do
 59       assert_difference("PostImage.count", 3) do
 60         post :create, params: {
 61           group_id: groups(:sportsball).id,
 62           post: {
 63             text: "New post!?",
 64             is_pinned: "true"
 73           }
 74         }
 75
 76         post = Post.last
 77         assert_equal true, post.is_pinned
 78
 79         assert_response :created, response.body
 80         assert valid_json?(response.body), "Invalid json: #{response.body}"
 81
 82         json = JSON.parse(response.body).deep_symbolize_keys
 83         
 84       end
 85     end
 86   end
```

**PushNotifications**

```
class PushNotifications
  def initialize
    @fcm = FCM.new(ENV["FCM_SERVER_KEY"])
  end

  def new_post_in_group(post:)
    registration_ids = all_users_except_author(post)
    author           = post.user
    group            = post.group
    return unless registration_ids

    options = {
      notification: {
        title: "#{author.name} har skrevet en melding i #{group.name}",
        text: post.text.truncate(27)
      },
      data: {
        notification:
        {
          avatar: author.avatar,
          # comment_id: '646',
          group_id: group.id,
          issued_at: Time.now,
          full_name: author.name,
          id: 700, # 700 = new post. The client knows what to do by looking at this id.
          post_id: post.id,
          role_id: author.role_id(group)
        }
      }
    }
    response = @fcm.send(registration_ids, options)
    puts "Sendt: #{response}" if ENV["DEBUG"]
  end

  private

  def all_users_except_author(post)
    recipients = post.group.users.pluck(:fcm_token)
    recipients.delete(post.user.id)
    recipients
  end
end
```

**config/initializers/PushNotifications.rb**

```
  1 require "#{Rails.root}/lib/push_notifications"
  2
  3 puts "initialize PushNotifications"
  4 PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS ||= PushNotifications.new
```

Comment: @spickermann it seems `Regexp` is completely acceptable per [Matching uris using regular expressions](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock#matching-uris-using-regular-expressions). OP can you show us the actual test `PostsControllerTest#test_should_create_post`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including both, the WebMock setup and the request.

Comment: @Stefan Complete example added. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test failed because I had added stub_request to the spec_helper. The failing test was not rspec, but an ordinary ActionController::TestCase test. My bad! :-|